# how to set_rule to Insert in one of two fields?

Tags: php, codeigniter

If i want that out of two input field one has to be filled correctly. then only the form get submitted else it should show an error. **How can we do it using `set_rule` function in class `form_validation` in codeigniter.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say (for the purposes of this example) that you want to validate **EITHER** an email address **OR** a phone number, then in it's simplest form...

```
// If no email address, phone is required
if ( ! $this->input->post('email')) {
   $this->form_validation->set_rules('phone', 'Phone Number', 'trim|numeric|min_length[11]|required');
} else {
   $this->form_validation->set_rules('phone', 'Phone Number', 'trim|numeric|min_length[11]');
}

// If no phone number, email is required
if ( ! $this->input->post('phone')) {
   $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email Address', 'trim|valid_email|required');
} else {
   $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email Address', 'trim|valid_email');
}
```

...you could probably tidy it up a bit but that's the general idea of what I think you're trying to get.

Hope it helps!!